# problem on PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am trying to design pcb, i have one dout, my question is that,
two signal travel parallel both are worked on 3V3 Volt, what is the procedure for calculating trace clearence between two trace.

Comment: At 3V3, your only considerations are crosstalk (unlikely to be a problem for you) and what your board maker can make.  Start with 0.012" tracks and 0.012" gaps.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html ?

Comment: At what frequency?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of PCB trace calculators on-line e.g. this one: http://www.desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/TraceWidth.html or this: http://www.microexample.com/PCB-Trace-width-calculator.php

But for those voltages the limiting factor will probably  be the capabilities of your PCB manufacturing facility.

Answer (score 1):

Based on IPC-2221A standards, if you have 3.3V signals on two parallel traces, the following clearances may apply:

- For external traces (no soldermask): 0.1mm between tracks
- For internal traces (inner board layers): 0.05mm between tracks
- For coated traces (with soldermask): 0.05mm between tracks

If you're designing a PCB to be professionally produced, chances are the last two will apply. You can choose which clearance is applicable based on your project.

However, 0.1mm/0.05mm is very tiny, so the distance between the tracks is really not important at such low voltages. You will be limited at this point to the capabilities of your manufacturer. Generally I use a standard clearance of 10mil (0.254mm) unless the board is crowded and I need to create more room by pushing traces closer together.

As for the thickness of your traces, that's a whole different problem which is based on the amount of current the tracks need to carry. There are IPC standards for that as well.